# Make firebase call in swift initializer

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app lets users message each other using Firestore. Each user is stored in firebase, as well as each conversation. Every conversation in firebase contains references to both users that are linked to that conversation, the reference is their UID. In my app, the current user is already initialized, but when they select a preview for a conversation to open and view messages, that conversation has to be fully initialized from firebase. That initializer and convenience initializer for the firebase dictionary is showed here:

```
class Conversation {
 
    var id: String? 
    var otherUser: User
    var messages: [Message]


    init(id: String?, otherUser: User, messages: [Message]) {
        
        self.id = id
        self.messages = messages
        self.otherUser = otherUse

    }
    

    convenience init?(data: [String: Any]) {
        do {
            
            guard let id = data["id"] as? String else {
                throw(DataError.fetchingVariable("Conversation.id"))
            }
            
            guard let userOneUid = data["userOne"] as? String else {
                throw(DataError.fetchingVariable("Conversation.userOneUid"))
            }
            
            guard let userTwoUid = data["userTwo"] as? String else {
                throw(DataError.fetchingVariable("Conversation.userTwoUid"))
            }
            
            //Check here which user is the current user by UID, and then get user data for other user and initialize that user
            
            var otherUserUid: String
            if currentUser.uid == userOneUid {
                otherUserUid = userTwoUid
            } else {
                otherUserUid = userOneUid
            }
            
            User.getUserData(for: otherUserUid) { data in
                
                let otheUser = User(info: data) //This is the initialized user, but currently it's stuck in this completion handler.
                
            }

            
            guard let messagesData = data["messages"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
                throw(DataError.fetchingVariable("Conversation.messages"))
            }
            
            var messages = [Message]()
            
            for messageData in messagesData {
                guard let message = Message(data: messageData) else {
                    let errorSender = Sender(senderId: "Error", displayName: "Error")
                    
                    let errorMessage = Message(sender: errorSender, messageId: "error", sentDate: Date(), kind: .text("Error fetching message..."))
                    
                    messages.append(errorMessage)
                    break
                }
                
                messages.append(message)
            }
            
            self.init(id: id, otherUser: otherUser, messages: messages)
            

        } catch {
            //This catch currently just prints the error, it will be handled afterward.
            print("Error initializing conversation with data: \(data), error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

And this is the func to retrieve user data, which returns user data in a completion handler:

```
extension User {
static public func getUserData(for Uid: String, completion: @escaping ([String: Any]) -> Void) {
        db.collection("users").document(Uid).getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                guard let documentData = document.data() else {
                    print("Error unwrapping document data for user: \(Uid)")
                    return
                }
                
                completion(documentData)
                
            } else {
                print("Error initializing user with uid \(Uid), does not exists.")
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that the other user needs to be initialized when the conversation is initialized, but I'm not able to make a call to firebase in the initializer, and I'm not sure the proper way to use completion handlers to ensure this user is initialized and then used to initialize the conversation. The other user needs to be initiated to access its name, profile image, and to have there information ready incase the user opens their profile from the messaging view controller.

Comment: Initializers and completion handlers aside, what exactly is the user experience or use case supposed to be here?

Comment: The question is a bit vague and the provided code doesn't tell us much. For example what does this *throw(DataError.fetchingVariable("Conversation.id"))* do? Why do users need to be 'initialized' to be in a conversation - where is that code? How are you reading user data from Firebase? Then what are you doing with the data once read? Can you clarify the question, the code and tell us what in the code isn't working?

Comment: @Jay I've updated the question, thanks

Comment: Seems over complicated at first glance. When a user authenticates, you know their uid from the Auth variable so it's not clear why you need to keep 'other info' in memory. Also, when there's a conversation the user wants to review, you'll know the other users uid (as you mentioned) so what else needs to be initialized? Lastly, *have there information ready incase the user opens their profile* - you can simply retrieve that via their uid. Is there something more? Why retrieve a bunch of information if it's not going to be used?

Comment: @Jay well the conversations are stored in a completely separate collection than the users, so it’s necessary to store both uids in the conversation document in firebase, and then when it’s fetched, check which user is the current and which will be the recipient. And as to why the user needs to be initialized: I need there name, profile image url, and I wanted to have the user object ready to pass to another view controller in case the user wants to perform another action from that screen.

Comment: Ok, I get the flow. You only really need to load other users data when it's needed. For example, here on SO; Your question has a username below it. When I click your question via  a list, SO knows your user id and gets your name; then it shows the question and name. When I then click your name, it knows your user id and gets your user details and then shows that in another window. If you want to display usernames in a list, you can do that as you are populating your dataSource. Load the messages and as you iterate over each, get the username from Firebase and store it with the message.

Answer (score 1):

First, when the app itself launches, why don't you download the current user's information right away and store that in memory? Perhaps create a singleton object called `CurrentUser` that stores this data that any future object, like this view controller, can read from. This will save you from making network calls on the current user's data. Then whenever the user changes their own data in the app (like a display name change), update it both remotely (in the database) and locally (in memory). Perhaps an even better way would be to attach a snapshot listener to this `CurrentUser` object that listens for updates to the current user's data so whenever this data does change, it will automatically update `CurrentUser`.

Second, you should probably make a function in this view controller (or a data manager object that this view controller interacts with) that is responsible for fetching both the conversation data and the user data. When both of these chunks of data are obtained, then render the conversation in the UI. You can use a dispatch group to coordinate these separate async tasks. Regardless of what you do, I would avoid placing any network operations within the initializers of data models, like `Conversation`. When you are initializing an object, you should have the data necessary to initialize it right then and there.

Comment: I actually do store the CurrentUser in a singleton for the whole app, I just didn't include that in the question in an attempt to simplify the question. So you suggest I grab the the user data, and then on completion of that, I initialize the conversation? Something like this? 
`
let conversationID = "foo"
Conversation.getOtherUserData(forConversation id: conversationID) { otherUser in
    let conversation = Conversation(id: conversationID, otherUser: otherUser)
}
`

Comment: @TavesWalker how do you initialize the conversation? I suspect you need to get documents from Firestore for that as well, right?

Comment: @TavesWalker I would stick with my answer even after the edit. When the user opens a conversation, simply have a function, one that is separate from any model object, grab both the user data and the conversation data at the same time. After they both come in, load the UI. If you already have the conversation data before you open the view controller then just get the user data and once that comes in, then load the UI. Do all of this outside of the models' initializers. Those initializers should not contain network calls.